# Using a proper preposition

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which choice fits the best for my example below:

> I waited for you (...) 12 o’clock, but you didn't come (...), so I got on a taxi and left.
>   a) until / until that time
>   b) until / by that time
>   c) by / until that time
>   d) by / by that time

For me all of these choices work, but I'm sure one of them is the most natural one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first clause, only *until* is permissible, not *by*.

> I waited for you **until** 12 o'clock.

In the second clause, only *by then* suits the context. *Until then* would imply that "you" **did** come at 12 o'clock.

> You didn't come **until then**, so I was pretty angry when you arrived.

However, the simple past is unlikely; you should have a past perfect, because you are speaking of the 'state' current at 12 o'clock which caused you to leave:

> You **hadn't come** by then, so I got on a taxi and left.

Comment: Thanks StoneyB
But three more questions:
First: do you mean I have to use "until then" and "by then" instead of "until that time" and "by that time"?
Second: Do you mean using "until then" in this specific context means that he finally arrived, while using "by then" means he didn't arrive at all?
Why in the first clause the only possible word is "until" or rather why "by" doesn't work?

Comment: @A-friend: In this context *then* and *that time* are equivalent; you may use either. *Until* marks the endpoint of a telic verb (an activity or state, see [this ELL link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info)), so *did not come until 12:00* means that 12:00 was the endpoint of his not coming. *By* marks the 'deadline' for telic verbs, so it cannot be used with *wait*, which is a non-telic activity.

Comment: thanks for the link; I read it, but there was nothing about the verb "wait" as a telic / nnon-telic verb.

Comment: @A-friend Well, no; but telic and non-telic are defined there. I can't very well list all the verbs in English and tell you what their lexical aspects are ... I'm an old man and I doubt I'm going to live that long! *Wait* is an activity verb, and activity verbs are +DURATION -TELICITY

Comment: Thank you very much StoneyB. In my eastern culture if someone says such thing like you  mentioned above, we say "may you live long" and this was not a complement. I personally always used to say it to older people, because I think really highly of them and if we younger people have something is because of their existence. Nevertheless thank you very much for the help. I will try to find some information about it using Google. ;)

Comment: @A-friend: The best way to learn how to use a word or expression is to look at many instances of how it is used. A valuable tool for this is the [corpora](http://corpus.byu.edu/) at Brigham Young University, where you may navigate to a particular corpus (e.. COCA, the Corpus of Contemporary American English) and enter (for example) 'wait' ... you will get a list of uses, and their sources, classified by type, and you may see them in a moderately long context. It takes a little learning, but it is worth it.

Comment: Perfect link. Thank you very much Stoney. It was really nice of you to help me.

Comment: @A-friend: That's what we do here!

Comment: I'd be tempted to just use *until* for the first part, and nothing for the second:  "I waited until 12:00, but you didn't come, so I left and got a taxi."

Comment: @Jim Me, too. Or "but you never came, so..."

Comment: @jim agreed, but here I was not going to discuss only about natural way of saying the statement above, but I needed to realize the idiomatic usage of each preposition in this specific context. Anyway thank you for the useful comment. ;)